# getShortestPath; How can I fix this code

Tags: java

I have been struggling with this code. Eclipse keeps telling me to change the type of startnode and endnode to node. I have done this and I have no headway. Can someone please explain to me what do, because its hard getting the shortest path. if is possible point to me my errors and how to fix it. thanks in advance

```
public List<Coordinate> getShortestPath(Coordinate start, Coordinate end) {

    Coordinate start = board.get(start.getRow()).get(start.getCol()); **eclipse ask me to change type of start to node**

    Coordinate end = board.get(end.getRow()).get(end.getCol());
```

**eclipse ask me to change type of start and also of end to node**

```
    List<Coordinate> dispenser = new LinkedList<Coordinate>();
    dispenser.add(start);

    Map<Coordinate, Coordinate> predecessors = new HashMap<Coordinate, Coordinate>();

    while (!dispenser.isEmpty()){
        Coordinate current = dispenser.remove(0);
        if(current == end){
            break;
        }//end of if
        for(Coordinate n : getNeighbors(current)){
            if(!predecessors.containsKey(n)){
                predecessors.put(n, current);
                dispenser.add(n);    
 return constructPath(predecessors, start, end);

   }//end of while
 List<Coordinate> path = new LinkedList<Coordinate>();

if (predecessors.containsKey(endNode)) {
    Coordinate currNode = endNode;
    while (currNode != startNode) {
        path.add(0, currNode);
        currNode = predecessors.get(currNode);
    }//end of while
    path.add(0, startNode);
}//end of if

return path;
 }

     List<Coordinate> shortest = new LinkedList<Coordinate>();

     for (Node p: path){

         shortest.add( ((coordinate) p).getCoordinate()); **eclipse says cannot cast from node to coordinate** I am not so good with java, I need help *

   }

     return shortest;

 }
```

Comment: Where and how did you declare `startNode` and `endNode`?  I can't figure out what Eclipse is trying to tell you without that key piece of information.

Comment: thanks for your response. eclipse says change type of start to node :Coordinate start = board.get(start.getRow()).get(start.getCol());

         Coordinate end = board.get(end.getRow()).get(end.getCol());

Comment: We don't know what `board` looks like.  Still can't help you.

Comment: It is for a quoridor player module. the code is pretty long but then i will just post it

Comment: Without seeing any more code, it appears that the `get` method on your board returns a `Node` of some kind, not a `Coordinate`.  But without more code, I have no idea what you should do to get a `Coordinate`.  You should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get an idea of the best way to ask this kind of question.

Comment: now i understand..thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler (through Eclipse) is telling you exactly what's wrong: you have a `Node`, but you're treating it like a `Coordinate`.  The question is not "Why is it a `Node`?", but "Why did you think it would be a `Coordinate`?".

To answer the "Why is it a `Node`?" question anyway...  `board` is a collection of collections.  Your first `board.get` returns one of those inner collections, which contains `Node` objects.  The second `.get` on that returns a `Node`.  So either stop storing `Node`s there, or stop expecting to find `Coordinate`s there.

Your two problem lines still look suspicious:

```java
public List<Coordinate> getShortestPath(Coordinate start, Coordinate end) {
    Coordinate start = board.get(start.getRow()).get(start.getCol());
    Coordinate end = board.get(end.getRow()).get(end.getCol());
    // ...
}
```

`getShortestPath` is given two `Coordinate` objects called `start` and `end`, and the first thing it does is replace them with two new `Coordinate` objects, *also* called `start` and `end`.  What was wrong with the ones you were given?  Why would you know better than your caller what `start` and `end` should be?